# The @isset directive is not been rendered by Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-blade, laravel-views

I'm developing a `blade view` on Laravel 5.4 which tests if a variable is set. If it is not set, the `blade` must present a little piece of html code placed into it. The problem is Laravel ignores or doesn't recognize the `@isset` directive rendering the string as if it was a simple html code. See the picture:

[image]

I have done a ugly workaround using `@if(! empty($test) )`. And I already tried to clean the cache with `php artisan cache:clear`.

Did someone know something that can cause this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is that `@endissets` a typo? If it is, change it to `@endisset`

Comment: Yes, it is! But it does not solve the problem. (I'd be ashamed if it was a foolish typo! Thank God it wasn't! )

Comment: The only issue I could think about Blade printing this directive is if the version of the framework is not updated to 5.4, since `@isset` was introduced in Laravel 5.4. Otherwise it will print it as text.

Comment: Using `php artisan --version` it returns Laravel Framework 5.4.15. It's so strange... It looks like a beginner issue but I'm developing with Laravel more than a year (this is a problem that I spent time in the first week of developing).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem updating `Laravel Framework` from **5.4.15** to **5.4.36**.

First, stop your server (if you are using `php artisan serve`).

Then run `composer update` on root directory of the project.

Probably you need to run `php artisan cache:clear` before serve the project again, in my case it wasn't necessary.

It's a strange behavior of Laravel witch probably is a little bug on Laravel Framework 5.4.15 or earlier.